# Realizar pirámide de caracteres

Tags: java

Hola gente buenas noches soy nuevo en esto de programación,y solo me aparece de un solo lado pues yo quiero que salga completo como la imagen GRACIAS

```
public static void main(string[] args) {

    int base = 8;

    for(int h =1; h <= base; h++) {

        for(int a= 1; a>= h; a++) {

            System.out.print("T");
        }
        System.out.printLn();

    }

}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow. Para empezar, debes comprender los ejemplos que te han dado en clase, o los ejercicios que ha resuelto el profesor. Acá puedes encontrar quien te eche un cable si te quedas atorado, pero difícilmente encontrarás quien haga tu tarea desde cero, el inicio y el principal esfuerzo te toca a ti. Cuando tengas un tiempo, te invito a leer [ask], que tiene los lineamientos generales de qué preguntas son bien recibidas por la comunidad. Un saludo.

Answer (score 2):

El código que planteas originalmente es incorrecto, primeramente tienes un bucle infinto ya que `a` siempre será mayor a `h`:

```
...
...
 for(int a= 1; a>= h; a++) {

            System.out.print("T ");
        }
...
...
```

Recuerda que debes insertar espacios para que se muestre cada fila correctamente y por cada fila aumentara el número de caracteres.

```
-------T
------TTT
-----TTTTT
----TTTTTTT
---TTTTTTTTT
--TTTTTTTTTTT
-TTTTTTTTTTTTT
TTTTTTTTTTTTTTT
```

Este código te ayudará a construir la pirámide:

```
   public static void main(String[] args) {


        int base = 8, j = 0;

        for(int i = 1; i <= base; ++i, j = 0) {

            //Inserta espacio parra acomodar el caracter en cada fila
            for(int espacio = 1; espacio <= base - i; ++espacio) {
                System.out.print(" ");
            }

            //Inserta caracter.
            while(j != 2 * i - 1) {
                System.out.print("T");
                ++j;
            }

            //Inserta nueva linea.
            System.out.println();
        }

    }
```

En base al código anterior obtendrías como salida:

```
       T
      TTT
     TTTTT
    TTTTTTT
   TTTTTTTTT
  TTTTTTTTTTT
 TTTTTTTTTTTTT
TTTTTTTTTTTTTTT
```